# Android - Released unknown imageData reference

Tags: android, google-maps, picasso

I know exactly why I'm getting this error but I can't figure out how to fix it. So What I'm doing it drawing a bunch of markers using Picasso where I implement a Target and load the Marker Icon once the image is done download. However, the user is able to click a tab which would clear the map view. So in an effort to try and fix it I don't use getMap.clear() but rather track the markers in a hashmap and when the map should clear I loop through the hashmap and remove the marker from the map and clear the hashmap, however I'm still getting this issue.

Here is the function to remove the markers:

```
private void clearCars() throws IllegalArgumentException {

    Iterator it = vehicles.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        Car aCar = (Car) pair.getValue();

        if (aCar.getCurrentMarker() != null) {
            if (aCar.getCurrentMarker().getmMarker() != null) {
                aCar.getCurrentMarker().getmMarker().remove();
            }
        }
    }

    vehicles.clear();
}
```

This method draws the cars:

```
private void validateMap(ArrayList<Object> data) {

    if (Theme.isCarTheme()) {

        for (Object anObject : data) {

            Car currentCar = (Car) anObject;

            String uniqueIndex = currentCar.getCarID() + "-" + currentCar.getVehicleNumber();

            CustomMarker aMarker = null;

            if (vehicles.containsKey(uniqueIndex)) {

                aMarker = ((Car) vehicles.get(uniqueIndex)).getCurrentMarker();
                aMarker.getmMarker().setPosition(currentCar.getCarLocation());

            } else {

                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.blank_image));
                options.position(currentCar.getCarLocation());
                currentCar.setCurrentMarker(new CustomMarker(mapViewLayout.getMapView().getMap().addMarker(options)));

                String strUrl = Constants.Car_IMAGE_URL + currentCar.getCarID() + assetType + ".png";

                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(strUrl).into(currentCar.getCurrentMarker());

                vehicles.put(uniqueIndex, currentCar);
            }

            vehicles.get(uniqueIndex).setHasUpdated(true);
        }

        Iterator it2 = vehicles.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it2.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it2.next();

            Car aCar = (Car) pair.getValue();

            if (aCar.isHasUpdated() == false) {
                it2.remove();
                aCar.getCurrentMarker().getmMarker().remove();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the marker class:

```
public class CustomMarker implements Target {

    Marker mMarker;

    public CustomMarker(Marker marker) {
        mMarker = marker;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return mMarker.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof CustomMarker) {
            Marker marker = ((CustomMarker) o).mMarker;
            return mMarker.equals(marker);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)  throws IllegalArgumentException {

        mMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }


    public Marker getmMarker() {
        return mMarker;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried implementing the solution offered here?[link][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523202/released-unknown-bitmap-reference-setting-marker-in-android]

Comment: There is no solution its just explaining whats causing the problem